# What is the 'prototype' property of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) says that every JavaScript object has a prototype property that is **not** actually called `prototype`:

> Every object in JavaScript has a built-in property, which is called
> its **prototype**. ... The property of an object that points to its
> prototype is not called `prototype`. Its name is not standard, but in
> practice all browsers use `__proto__`. The standard way to access an
> object's prototype is the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method.

Why then do React components have a property called exactly `prototype`?

I can see this property from the Javascript console when creating a React app with `create-react-app` and logging `App.prototype` to the console:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

console.log(App.prototype);
```

The log returns an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `App` is a `Component`.
- React's `Component` type (via `ComponentClass`) [is a JS `class` type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts).
- [All JS `class` types are actually `Function` objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-class-definitions) (as they're references to the class's constructor function).
- Consequently `App` inherits the `prototype` property that way.